# Concept of OOP in python

Tags: python-2.7, function, parameters

This is the main file of the code:

```
#for student registration in a college
from la_class import *
from la_class0 import *
from la_class1 import *

student1_name = Student(name1)
student1_pref = Branch(pref)

print("Student1 details : ",student1_name.name)
print("Student1 branch : ",student1_pref.preference )

student1_course = Course(core,el1,el2)

print("core course---",student1_course.core)
print("elective course---1.",student1_course.elective1)
print("elective course---2.",student1_course.elective2)
```

la_class file:

```
 #takes the student name input
 class Student:
  def __init__(self,name):
   self.name = name

 print("___student details___ ")
 name1 = raw_input("name1 > ")
```

la_class0 file:

```
 #this contains the preference operations 
 class Branch:
  def __init__(self,pref):
  self.preference = pref
 print("__________")
 print("(1.) __CSE__")
 print("(2.) __CCE__")
 print("(3.) __ECE__")
 print("(4.) __MME__")

 usr = raw_input("_choose the above preferences_ ")

 if usr is "1":
  pref = "CSE"
 elif usr is "2":
  pref = "CCE"
 elif usr is "3":
  pref = "ECE"
 else:
  pref = "MME"
```

la_class1 file:

```
#takes the input for courses
class Course():
 def __init__(self,core,elec1,elec2):
 self.core = core
 self.elective1 = elec1
 self.elective2 = elec2

print("___course-details___")
#core courses ---
print("--available-core-courses--")
print("(1.) __OOP__")
print("(2.) __COA__")
print("(3.) __SSC__")

co = raw_input("Choose any above course")
if co is "1":
 core = "OOP"
elif co is "2":
 core = "COA"
else:
 core = "SSC"
#Elective courses ---
print("Choose two elective courses")
print("(1.) __PTSP__","(2.) __YOGA__","(3.) __POC__")
el1 = raw_input("elective 1 : ")
el2 = raw_input("elective 2 : ")
```

Here the code works for only one student object i.e. **student1**, how to implement the code so that the user can have as much student registration as he want to (it should be object oriented)?

Comment: It is a bit unclear to me what you want to do? You want to construct one student object carrying all the names?

Comment: like in c we can take array input (self,name[10],pref[10]) .THis way in python

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
class Student:
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # args is a list, positional
    # kwargs is a dict
    self.names = args
    self.first_name = args[0]

student = Student ("john", "doe")
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how to use this thing and make an instance?

Comment: I update the example. If you want to use dynamical number of parameters

Answer (score 0):

Python is dynamically typed, meaning every variable can store an integer, string, list, tuple, function, object, class, etc.

So you can simply construct a list like:

```
names = ["tom","alice","bob"]
preferences = ["cse","math","lang"]
```

and for instance feed it to a constructor:

```
student0 = Student(names[0],prefs[0]) #student Tom likes cse
student1 = Student(names[1],prefs[1]) #student Alice likes math
student2 = Student(names[2],prefs[2]) #student Bob likes lang
```

since `names[0]` will access the 0-th element of `names`.

You can even easily construct a list of students by using `zip` and *list-comprehension*:

```
students = [Student(name,pref) for name,pref in zip(names,preferences)]
```

which is equivalent to:

```
# equivalent to
students = [Student("tom","cse"),Student("alice","math"),Student("bob","lang")]
```

Comment: In this method, while 'printing' you need to 'call' the 'class' each time.

Comment: what do you mean with "printing"? You want to construct one `Student`s object that contains *all* the names? Isn't that counterintuitive with the name *Student*? I expect a `Student` class to talk about, well, one student.

Comment: Is there any way of using 'loop' so that the code automatically prints the name given by the user instead of using repeated 'Student("name","pref") '.

Comment: I still don't follow what you aim to do. You can print names without constructing a `Student` at all. But then I don't see why specifying a class `Student` was usefull in the first place. Can you please rewrite your question with input and requested output.

Comment: I think now you can analyze my Q clearly, please help..I am new in OOP